# How to change position back button in google street view?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need change position into google maps street view from left to right - 
[image]

My code:

```js
new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.197363, 8.494004),
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControlOptions: {
            //position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },);
```

How change position or rewrite  HTML code for button?

Comment: Only the Back button or the entire ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible! I found solution:

```js
//init map and set options
var gmap = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

var thePanorama = gmap.getStreetView();

// change view
google.maps.event.addListener(thePanorama, 'visible_changed', function() {
  // Display your street view visible UI
  if (thePanorama.getVisible()) {
    
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      map_canvas, {
        addressControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, // <- change position
        }
      });
    // rewrite default options  
    gmap.setStreetView(panorama);

  } else {
    console.log('show default UI');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently we do not support the re-positioning of that control in our API.

A CSS workaroud like the one provided by @el solo lobo may work, but in the future if we change our CSS or another part of the map, it'll break.

A better solution, is to create your own controls. This way you have total control on where they appear, how they look and what they do. For more information on this topic you can read the following documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Also, I would like to note that `streetViewControlOptions` [only changes the position of the pegman icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewControlOptions), not the position of the controls as you intend.

If however, you don't feel like creating your own control set, and just wish to change the position of our other controls, I recommend the following example:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

@Slava's solution put me on the track, but like me you may need a more generic solution (also, Slava's solution did not work quite well for me, the street view panorama was not showing the first time I was dropping the little yellow man).

We just need to replace the street view config, we don't need to listen for the default one to show up:

```
const streetView = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(gmap.getDiv(), {
    visible: false,
    enableCloseButton: true,
    addressControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    }
});

gmap.setStreetView(streetView);
```

Here, I set `{ visible: false }` so the panorama does not open immediately (ie. you'll have to drop the pawn), and I use `gmap.getDiv()` to reuse the Maps container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the position of the entire area, just do

```
.widget-titlecard{
 float: right;
}
```

This works in the inspector on maps.google.com, haven´t tested it on my own page.

The css for the entire Area looks like this then, but I guess you just need to set `float: right` here

```
.widget-titlecard {
outline: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top: 14px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 10;
background-color: rgba(34,34,34,.8);
-webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
transition: left 0.5s;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
float: right; //This was added
```

}

But this is more a css hack.. the is probably an API setting for this, but I don´t know. Maybe someone post´s a better solution for this.

Comment: `.widget-titlecard` - how to add this class in navigation button? I haven't this class by default.